# what are the normal server isolation technologies?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, isolated-network

We have some development servers which are used by outsourcing companies, from these development servers, they can `ssh` into production database servers, can you tell me how to isolate servers from accessing each other?

Comment: With a firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Change the login and password on production servers? Firewall them in your router, maybe?

If SSH is your only concern, and the dev servers have to be able to otherwise access the prod servers, you can disable the shell for those particular credentials (i.e. set the shell to `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`.)

Finally, if those particular accounts do have to have SSH access, just not from those servers (although at this point I would suggest you to rethink your security policy,) you can deny them access by whitelisting allowed IP addresses (better) or blacklisting the unnecessary addresses (not so good.):

**Whitelisting:**

In /etc/hosts.allow add:

```
sshd: [your allowed addresses/subnets]
sshd: [your allowed addresses/subnets]
sshd: [your allowed addresses/subnets]
```

(multiple entries are possible)

In /etc/hosts.deny add:

```
sshd: ALL
```

**Blacklisting:**

The same but the other way around. In /etc/hosts.deny add:

```
sshd: [disallowed addresses/subnets]
```

No necessity to add anything to /etc/hosts.allow.

And then restart your SSH server (the sshd service, not the entire server.) Just in case, if SSH is the only way you have to access those servers, do leave a connection running while you do this, so you don't lose access in case something doesn't work and you have to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You may setup a bastion host in your environment to allow ssh to production and whitelist it's IP in the firewall.

For authentication and authorization you can setup a centralized Identity Management solution. There are some open source solutions which lets you do that and [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) is one of them which is a free IDM solution. 
It helps you manage linux users and hosts from one central location and enable single Sign-on authentication for all your systems, services and applications. It also helps you to control who has access to what through authorization policies for your identities.